# Stored Procedure Returns no columns Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have looked all over the internet, and have not been able to find a fix for my issue. I have a SPROC that I am trying to create an Entity Object for to use in my project, and I am getting this error, when I attempt to add an import function.

**The Selected stored procedure or function returns no columns**

Here is the SPROC SQL

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[RHS_LocationFullTextSearch]
@SearchText varchar(100)
as
Begin
 SET FMTONLY OFF
select relo.SearchID, relo.SearchText, relo.SearchType, relo.SourceTable,  relo.SourceTableRecordID
from RELOHomeSearch.dbo.RHS_LocationSearch relo (nolock)
where contains (SearchText, @SearchText)
End
```

The

Here is a screen of the error
[image: Error Message]

Here is a screen of the table object that the SPROC returns results of
[image: Table]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what flavor of sql is this?

Comment: SQL Server 2012 version 11.0.3128

Comment: what happens if you add `GO` after `SET FMTONLY OFF`

Comment: Try removing the `SET FMTONLY OFF` line. Most of the designers need to execute the query with `SET FMTONLY ON` to determine the columns returned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by taking out the where clause. For some reason the utility didn't like  it. Not sure why though.

Comment: The designer is probably passing `Null` to the parameter. The `Contains` method will raise an error if you pass `Null` as the search condition. If you add `If @SearchText Is Null Set @SearchText='""'` before the `SELECT`, it should work.